# How to dismiss a telprompt programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, telprompt

I am opening a dialog asking the user to call somewhere 
with this code :

```
-(void)callPhone:(NSString *)phone{
    NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%@",phone]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:phoneURL];
}
```

all is nice and great;

however, this dialog appears over a tableview, and i want, when the user begins scrolling the tableview behind the dialog, to automatically dismiss this dialog.

How ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't as `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:phoneURL];` ends up asking the OS to handle the URL.